# Does sending an image as a byte[] increase download speed?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image-processing

Does sending and image as a byte[] download faster than sending it as a BitmapImage? Assume I'm only downloading one image to a client application. Is this helpful or do I need to compress the image in order for it to download faster?

**EDIT:** I'm using downloading an image file through a WCF service.

Comment: What methods are you using to send the image in each case?

Comment: @Justin I'm downloading from a wcf service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether you send it as a `byte` or as a `BitmapImage`, the number of bytes sent will be the same. Or at least so close to the same as not to make a difference. The only way you're going to increase the speed is by reducing the number of bytes sent, typically by compressing the image.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of transport are you using? That's important. Generally though, when moving something over the wire it must be serialized, usually to a byte array. So you might save yourself the added step of serializing the BitmapImage instance, but transmission speed will remain the same.